# Which ports to open to ensure NFS mount succeeds?

Tags: linux, mount, opensuse, nfs

I set up an NFS server and client to mount some NFS volumes (all servers are SUSE Enterprise Linux 11 for the record). The mount was successful, until I rebooted my machine and they were gone - it seemed they weren't reloaded from /etc/fstab. The relevant lines of fstab are below:

```
myhost01:/data      /data nfs    nfsvers=3,rw,sync,_netdev  0 0
myhost01:/data2      /data2 nfs  nfsvers=3,rw,sync,_netdev  0 0
```

I was curious, so I tried a sudo mount -a -v myself to see what was going on, and what I saw surprised me.

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Apr  6 14:03:26 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=X.X.X.XX'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying X.X.X.XX prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying X.X.X.XX prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 60219
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying X.X.X.XX prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 36414
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - 
Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=X.X.X.XX'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying X.X.X.XX prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying X.X.X.XX prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 60219
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
```

In addition to the standard NFS port (2049), there's a random UDP and TCP port being tried, which I hadn't allowed through my security groups. I opened these, and the NFS was mounted successfully using my manual attempt, but on a second reboot, the ports changed again, and thus the mount from /etc/fstab failed again. My question is, what range of ports do I have to allow to ensure NFS works in all cases on reboot?

Comment: There are ways for parts of NFS to set some daemons to use fixed ports vs. random ports.  http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/security.html

Comment: Where is the config file for setting these parameters? I'm not actually executing anything on boot, fstab is.

Comment: These are settings on the NFS server IIRC.  I haven't dealt with this in a while (ditched NFS and went to CIFS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS(v2 and v3) utilizes multiple services to accomplish everything it needs to do. I'll cover their port configurations below:

#### portmapper

Uses port 111 for TCP and UDP for Server and Client side.

#### nfsd

For NFS v4 this is all that is needed. It runs on port 2049 for TCP and UDP on the NFS server side.

#### mountd

You edit the `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` on the nfsserver and configure the port with this parameter:

`MOUNTD_PORT=`

TCP and UDP would need to be opened on the server side.

#### lockd

(SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 SP2 and higher)

In the `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` you'll find and set the parameters as desired:

`STATD_PORT=
LOCKD_TCPPORT=
LOCKD_UDPPORT=`

#### rquotad

This one is only needed if you're using NFS quotas. The port would be 4003 for TCP and UDP on the server.

Source: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7000524